# lxml-3.4.0 - Undefined symbols

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, lxml, python-3.4

I've got lxml-3.4.0 mostly built, with --static-deps. How can I get these few remaining Undefined symbols wired in?

Note that gcc here is compiled to use the Solaris linker:

```
# LDSHARED=/usr/bin/ld \
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/full/path/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2/lib:/usr/lib \
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-Bdynamic -Wl,-lc -Wl,-lsocket -Wl,-lnsl -Wl,-Bstatic -Wl,-lxslt" \
python3.4 setup.py build_ext -i --static-deps --multicore=1
```

...

```
building 'lxml.etree' extension
/usr/gcc/4.8/bin/gcc -m32 -O3 -fPIC -DPIC -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -m32 -O3 -fPIC -DPIC -I/export/home/drlou/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2/include --I/full/path/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2/include/libxml2 -I/build/path/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2/include/libxslt -I/full/path/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2/include/libexslt -I/full/path/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.solaris-2.11-i86pc.32bit-3.4/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
/usr/bin/ld -Wl,-Bdynamic -Wl,-lc -Wl,-lsocket -Wl,-lnsl build/temp.solaris-2.11-i86pc.32bit-3.4/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o /full/path/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libiconv.a /full/path/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libxslt.a /full/path/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libxml2.a /full/path/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libexslt.a -L/full/path/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2/lib -L/usr/lib -lz -lm -lpython3.4m -o /full/path/lxml/src/lxml/etree.cpython-34m.so
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
gcry_md_hash_buffer                 /full/path/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libexslt.a(crypto.o)
lzma_end                            /full/path/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libxml2.a(xzlib.o)
gcry_cipher_close                   /full/path/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libexslt.a(crypto.o)
gcry_cipher_open                    /full/path/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libexslt.a(crypto.o)
lzma_code                           /full/path/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libxml2.a(xzlib.o)
gcry_check_version                  /full/path/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libexslt.a(crypto.o)
libiconv_close                      /full/path/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libxml2.a(encoding.o)
gcry_strerror                       /full/path/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libexslt.a(crypto.o)
gcry_cipher_setkey                  /full/path/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libexslt.a(crypto.o)
libiconv_open                       /full/path/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libxml2.a(encoding.o)
gcry_cipher_decrypt                 /full/path/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libexslt.a(crypto.o)
gcry_cipher_encrypt                 /full/path/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libexslt.a(crypto.o)
lzma_properties_decode              /full/path/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libxml2.a(xzlib.o)
lzma_auto_decoder                   /full/path/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libxml2.a(xzlib.o)
libiconv                            /full/path/lxml/build/tmp/libxml2/lib/libxml2.a(encoding.o)
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to /full/path/lxml/src/lxml/etree.cpython-34m.so
error: command '/usr/bin/ld' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: One is from liblzma.a, the others look like iconv and libgcrypt.

Comment: Sadly, neither: 
 -Wl,-liconv  - nor -
 -Wl,-lgcrupt 
get us there...
libiconv is meant to be static here, so that's not a path forward...
and the Solaris linker hates me sending it a "-Wl,-Bstatic -Wl,-liconv" here.